# Restore in app purchase windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In App Purchase functionality in my Windows Phone app. It is in beta version.
I have bought some products when testing the app.

So how do I restore products purchased state? I just want to test the functionalaty of the newly on the same device.

**UPDATE**: For example i have bought SomeProductName and test functionality. Now i need to mark SomeProductName as not bought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring the state of a purchased product is not possible in test using a beta app as you wanted. It is only possible in "Test using the emulator" or "Test using the emulator with real in-app purchase". See the section "Testing in-app purchase" (row "Allows resetting purchases") in this blog post: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/11/27/options-for-publishing-windows-phone-beta-apps-and-testing-in-app-purchase.aspx

Althought I guess there are some work arounds which should work, such as:

- Create a copy of the product with a new ID
- Submit new version of the beta app

Comment: Thank you for answer and for edited my question ))
But i want something else. For example i have bought SomeProductName and test functionality. Now i need to mark SomeProductName as not bought.